# Passing base_margin to xgboost model as part of sklearn pipeline in Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, xgboost

I was trying to pass the `base_margin` to the xgboost in `fit()` as part of the sklearn pipeline.

My code would work if you swap `base_margin` with `sample_weight` which is also a parameter in `fit()` so I am not sure why it could not recognize `base_margin`.

Due to some deployment constraints, I can only implement xgboost in a sklearn pipeline so please don't provide alternative answers.

```
# packages
import sklearn
import xgboost
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer
from xgboost import XGBRegressor 
import numpy as np

# Get boston dataset
boston = load_boston()
x, y = boston.data, boston.target

# Define offset
offset = np.ones(X.shape[0])

# sklearn pipeline
## identity transformation with XGBRegressor
pipeline_sklearn = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('preprocessor', FunctionTransformer()),
    ('regressor', XGBRegressor(
        n_etimators = 100,
        learning_rate = 0.01,
        random_state=0 
                               ))])

pipeline_sklearn.fit(X,y,regressor__base_margin = offset)
```

Results:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-ee36c60ebc2d> in <module>
----> 1 pipeline_sklearn.fit(X,y,regressor__base_margin = offset)

/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    352                                  self._log_message(len(self.steps) - 1)):
    353             if self._final_estimator != 'passthrough':
--> 354                 self._final_estimator.fit(Xt, y, **fit_params)
    355         return self
    356 

TypeError: fit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'base_margin'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not support on version 0.90 but I can confirm it's working on v1.2.1